# Is there a way to get a property name that annotated with @ApiProperty(security="is_granted('ATTRIBUTE')") in custom security voter?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Just discovered new exiting feature in API Platform 2.6.4 that helps to check access to any property of a resource (entity).

```
class Book
{
    //...

    /**
     * @var string Property viewable and writable only by users with ROLE_ADMIN
     *
     * @ApiProperty(security="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     */
    private $adminOnlyProperty;
}
```

So I tried to make a custom Security Voter that checks if the property is in allowed fields.

```
class PropertyVoter extends Voter
{
    protected function supports(string $attribute, $subject): bool
    {
        return in_array($attribute, ['ATTRIBUTE']);
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute(string $attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
        }

        // Subject should be a name of the property
        if (!in_array($subject, $user->getAllowedProperties())) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Than changed annotation above to

```
class Book
{
    //...

    /**
     * @var string Property viewable and writable only by users with ROLE_ADMIN
     *
     * @ApiProperty(security="is_granted('ATTRIBUTE')")
     */
    private $adminOnlyProperty;
}
```

But faced with issue, that I cant get the name of the field, that was annotated with @ApiProperty annotation.

So the question. Is there a way to get property name inside custom voter?

Comment: The name of the field is used only for serialization/deserialization so you "can't" access it in a voter like this. Did you check with ReflectionClass and ReflectionProperty to read annotations?

Comment: Yes, saw it in documentation, but can't figure out how to use it in the voter